# Is it possible to upload image to server and submit form to database at the same time?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I've created a form that allows client to create a blog. I want the form to submit to database and upload image to server when submitted. So far the all of the info gets to the database, but the image does not upload to server.

I guess what I'm asking is it possible for the form to perform two functions at once and how is this done? Thanks.

My form code is below.

```
 <form name="my-form" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" id="my-form" class="my-form">




            <fieldset>
                    <section>
                      <label class="label">Blog Title <strong class="red-font">50 characters MAX with spaces</strong></label>
                      <label class="input">
                          <i class="icon-append fa fa-tag"></i>
                          <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                      </label>
                    </section>

                <section>
                    <label class="label">descrition <strong class="red-font">150 characters MAX with spaces</strong></label>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-edit"></i>
                        <input type="4" name="desc" id="desc">
                    </label>
                </section>


                <section>
                    <label class="label">Keywords <strong class="red-font">6-8 groups of key words</strong></label>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-key"></i>
                        <input type="4" name="keywords" id="keywords">
                    </label>
                </section>


                <section>
                    <label class="label">Select A Category</label>
                    <label class="select" id="category">
                        <select name="category">
                          <?php
do {  
?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCategory['category']?>"<?php      if (!(strcmp($row_rsCategory['category'], $row_rsCategory['category']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rsCategory['category']?></option>
                          <?php
} while ($row_rsCategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategory));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCategory);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($rsCategory, 0);
  $row_rsCategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategory);
}
?>
                        </select>
                        <i></i>
                    </label>
                </section>


                 <section>
                    <label class="label">Add Blog Image </label>
                    <input type="file" name="blog_image" value="<?php 

//Properties of Image Upload
$name = $_FILES["myfile"] ["name"];
$type = $_FILES["myfile"] ["type"];
$size = $_FILES["myfile"] ["size"];
$temp = $_FILES["myfile"] ["tmp_name"];
$error = $_FILES["myfile"] ["error"];

if ($error > 0)

die ("Something went wrong. Please upload your image again");   
else
{   
move_uploaded_file($temp,"../../images/uploads/".$name);
}

?>">
                    </label>
                </section>  


                <section>
                    <label class="label">Type Blog</label>
                    <label class="textarea">
                        <!--<i class="icon-append fa fa-edit"></i>-->
                        <textarea rows="30" name="blog_content" id="blog_content"></textarea>
                    </label>
                </section>

                    <section>
                    <label class="label"><strong class="red-font">Publish to Web?</strong></label>
                    <label class="select" id="publish">
                        <select name="publish">
                          <option value="No" <?php if (!(strcmp("No", $row_rsBlogs['publish']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>No</option>
                          <option value="Yes" <?php if (!(strcmp("Yes", $row_rsBlogs['publish']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Yes</option>
                        </select>
                        <i></i>
                    </label>
                    </section>




            <footer>
                <button type="submit" class="button">Add Blog </button>
            </footer>
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="author" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_rsAdmin['name']; ?>">
        </fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="my-form">  
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag. Without it, file uploads won't work.

**Edit**: Also, your `<input type="file" ...>` field has been assigned the name `blog_image`, but in your PHP code you try to grab an uploaded file identified by the name `myfile`.

It also is not the best idea to fill the `<input type="file" ...>`'s `value` attribute with an error message. In fact, you shouldn't mess with this attribute at all. Better display any error messages before or after the `<input>` tag.

Comment: The enctype was definitely an oversight, but I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn error reporting on if it isn't already and see if PHP throws any errors or warnings. I'd recommend using the following to turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Also, check that your file upload path is correct,

Please ensure that the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute is present within your  also, which specifies how the data from the form should be encoded when submitting to a server.